# Passing a value from function to data() vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have emmited data from a component and I want to pass this data in data() function.

Here's what I mean

```
    export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      newlist
    };
  },
  components: {
    InputForms,
    List
  },
  methods: {
    handler(obj) {
      obj = this.newlist;
    }
  }
};
```

I want `obj` inside my `handler` method to be inside `data()`. Right now,this code is not compiling saying that `newlist` is not defined

Comment: If you want `newlist` to be reactive you have to initialize it with a value other than `undefined`. `data: () => ({ newlist: null })` will make it reactive. If you're using any of its properties inside the template, initiate it as an empty object: `data: () => ({ newlist: {}})`. Also, your method is wrong (you inverted the left and right sides of the assignment. It should be: `methods: { handler(obj) { this.newlist = obj; }}`. (I'm assuming you want to assign the value of `obj` to `this.newlist`, not the other way around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `newlist` to `newlist: {}` then inside your method swap what you already have:

```
handler(obj) {
   this.newlist = obj;
}
```